# Sending a Scheduled message or image to Whatsapp group programatically

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I just to know the way to send the Scheduled message or image at specific time say 12 AM for sending Birthday Greetings to the Whatsapp Group

We have case to prepare the message and attach whatsapp number to send a message from the iOS App using below code

```
func messageViaWhatsApp (sender: AnyObject) {
   let messageBody = "Hello"
   let whatsURL = "whatsapp://send?text=\(messageBody)"
   let whatsAppURL  = NSURL(string: whatsURL.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
   if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsAppURL!)
   {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsAppURL!)
   }
   else
   {
       let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Sorry", message: "Your device does not have whatsApp installed ", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
   }
}
```

But I need to Schedule a method that sends message or image to Specific whatsapp group as per specified time say 12 AM to send Greetings or Reminders or Meeting Information.

**Note**: I have searched for solution and found some similar solution but it is with Python language & Twilio

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-automate-whatsapp-messages-programmatically-from-your-computer-a042d0f4269f

Comment: i don't think this is possible

Comment: To schedule a message or image to be sent to a specific WhatsApp group at a specific time, you can use a combination of a cron job and the WhatsApp API.